# Cannot build C++ library with Windows Store support

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I have a static library written in C++, and I want to build that so that I can use it in a Windows Store app. 
The problem is that in Visual Studio 2015, when I click on Project->Retarget Solution and select the 10.0.xxx version of the SDK, the following text will be displayed in the output:

```
Retargeting End: 0 completed, 1 failed, 0 skipped
```

I am at a loss here, because no further information is provided.

I have also tried to manually target windows store by setting `Windows Store app support = Yes` in the project settings, but when building it I get the following error before any source has been built:

```
error MSB3843: Project "ProjectName" targets platform "Windows", but references SDK "Visual C++ 2015 Runtime for Universal Windows Platform Apps v14.0" which targets platform "UAP".
```

So how should I proceed with building this library for a Windows 10 Store app?

Comment: I think VS is very confused. There is no such thing as static libraries in .Net. VS would certainly not know what to do with a statically linked library for Windows Store.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are unfamiliar with static linking. My [The Basics of Creating a Static Library Using Visual C++](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/SamTomato/the-basics-of-creating-a-static-library-using-visual-cpp) will help. That shows how to create a statically (not dynamically) linked library and how to use it in C++ Console Application.

My [Managed C++ Wrapper For Unmanaged Code](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/SamTomato/managed-cpp-wrapper-for-unmanaged-code) shows how to create an interface from .Net to standard C++ that can link to the static library.

I hope you know how to do C++ programming.

Comment: I already have a library which I can use (link) no problem with windows desktop applications. However, my problem is that I can not link it with a Windows Store application. I don't even use any managed code or .NET just plain C++.